# Make files without an extension go through the PHP parser on nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, web-server

Due to legacy reasons I need to get the following scenario working on nginx and I seem to be struggling. Say I have a file in the document root just called 'info' without any file extension. Now this is a PHP file, but it doesn't have an extension, and can't be renamed for reasons I wont explain here. How would I write an nginx config to make this file be parsed by PHP.

I have actually tried renaming this file to info.php and then adding the following to my nginx config, I then tried to hit `http://{siteurl}/info` expecting it to internally re-write to `info.php`, but all it did was fall through to `index.html`.

```
location / {
        try_files @extensionless-php $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

Now I'm very new to nginx and so I assume I'm just missing something very basic. Previously in apache the config was like this to get this scenario to work...

```
    <LocationMatch "^/(info|...a few other files...)/?.*$">
            ForceType application/x-httpd-php
    </LocationMatch>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Note my `try_files` is a slight reshuffling of what you have in your example. Also I added `root` which should match your web root path.

```
location / {
    root /your/web/root/path
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.php index.html;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I did have it that way round initially, I just tried it the way round it currently is out of desperation. Although I have root set outside of the location block I can also try setting it within the location block to see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out:

```
location /info {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/www/info.php;
}
```

Actually makes sense now as I've bothered to read the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
## Your root already needs to be defined
# root /your/web/root/path
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php =404;
    index index.php index.html;
}
```

On hitting a url (`http://somedomain.com/some/path/action`) this will first try `some/path/action`, then `some/path/action/[index.php]`, then `some/path/action.php` and then fail with a 404 if it couldn't find the file.